# Why does all fields or feeds in thingspeak return all fields or feed instead of one or two?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code that read data on thing speak channel, my issue when i read the data either as one field. But the data on file format seem to read all feeds as data. To me this is an issue and yet it does not make any sense to a user. Question is there a way i can improve or thing-speak can enhance this documentation better for better readability? Here is my code both front end and Jquery reading data when, date range is downloaded with its checkbox. The checkbox are for option for that field if a user has to select and expectation is to be able to see that field only on the file format as either temperature or illuminance.

```
div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="temperature">
    <label class = "custom-control-label" for="temperature">Temperature</label>
    </div>

 <div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input type = "checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="illuminance">
   <label class = "custom-control-label" for = "illuminance">Illuminance</label>
  </div>   
 <div class ="custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input type ="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="button-state">
   <label class ="custom-control-label" for = "button-state">Button-State</label>

<!---Downloading File using 
Jquery with Buttons---->
  <div class="form-group"><br>
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
   <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>
    </div> 
  </div>


 // Downloading file into csv/json format.
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#download").click(function() {
           var count = 0;
           if($('#temperature').prop('checked')) count++;
           if($('#illuminance').prop('checked')) count++;
           if($('#button-state').prop('checked')) count++;
            if(count > 1) {
            window.location.href ='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.json?start=2019-11-14%2019:11:14&end=2019-11-18%2019:11:18';
            }else{

            // checking for one field being checked.

            if($('#temperature').prop('checked')) count--;
            if($('#illuminance').prop('checked')) count--;
            if($('#button-state').prop('checked')) count--;
            if(count < 1) {
              window.location.href = ' https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.json?start=2019-11-15%2019:11:15&end=2019-11-18';
            }
            }
          });
```

Comment: For your own benefits, I think it is better to refactor your code to make it maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was looking for was to modify my code, the example for this solution is below.

```
 $('#temperature').click(function() {
            var xcount = 0;
            if($('#temperature').prop('checked')) xcount--;
            if(xcount < 1) {
            window.location.href ='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.json';
            }
          });

  });
```

Notice, that my URL parameter changed, simply because i wanted to access one field for the checkbox if the user select it and in my file format it will pull out the date format if there is a date for that day as well number of data for that field. I have also used VS code using an extension called, REST client to see the constraint of Restful API.